# Dictionary in Python not printing correctly

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I want to print the contacts map but it doesn't work.

I removed all the if statements and it worked, but once I put the if statements in, it fails.

```
while True:
    contacts = {}
    print('''Type

    1 to Add/Update contact
    2 to Display all contacts
    3 to Search
    4 to Delete contact
    5 to Quit.''')
    choice = input("Which option?")
    if int(choice) == 1:
        contacts = {}
        name = input("Enter the name of the contact.")
        contact = input("Enter the phone number/email address.")
        contacts[name] = contact
    if int(choice) == 2:
        print("Done!")
        print(contacts)
    if int(choice) == 3:
        for key, value in contacts.items():
            print(key)
```

The output is simply {}.

Answer (score 1):

In each iteration of the while loop, you are clearing the `contacts` dictionary.

```
while True:
    contacts = {}
    ...
```

should be

```
contacts = {}
while True:
...
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks correct to me.
Maybe try

```
mycontact=contacts.keys()
phone=contacts.values()
print(mycontact)
print(phone)
```

If neighter of the solutions work (mine nor yours) try to doublecheck your if statement

```
choice = input("Which option?")
if int(choice) == 3:
    print(this works)
else
    print(this does not work)
```

Comment: Sorry, I made it too vague. I meant that the int(choice) == 1 and when i put in a name and contact (for example name = bob and contact = 911), when I did int(choice) == 2, all that printed out was {}, instead of {"Bob", 911}.